# Firebase Admin SDK JWT Auth Problem, Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-authentication

i'm having a issue about jwt auth in firebase admin sdk.
making request to server from client with jwt, returning unauthorized

i have this code on server for user sign-up

server.js

```
app.post('/auth/signup', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password, username } = req.body;
    if (isValidUsername(username)) {
      const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({
        email,
        password,
        displayName: username,
      });

      const userCredential = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);

      const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(userRecord.uid);

      // Send the ID token to the client
      res.json({ idToken: token });
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: 'Username must be in the range of 2-14 characters and not contain special characters.',
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

this code sending a jwt to client

and when user wants to have access the protected route on server, making get request to that route with Bearer Authorization Header.

client.js

```
    const abc = token => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/protected-route', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data));
    }
```

and server validating the token

server.js

```
const authenticateUser = (req, res, next) => {
  const idToken = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  console.log(idToken);

  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then((decodedToken) => {
    req.user = decodedToken;
    next();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
  });
};

app.get('/auth/protected-route', authenticateUser, (req, res) => {
  res.json({msg: 'Protected', user: req.user });
});
```

should send relevant user information to client.
but it returning 401 Unauthorized to client even token is new and valid(?)